# Trouble with perl Email::MIME

Tags: perl, email, mime

I'm having trouble using the Email:MIME module in perl. It's probably because I'm using it wrong, but finding examples for using it is difficult. I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to be using a scalar of the full message as an input, but it's not working. Here is my code and my output

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::POP3;
use Email::MIME;
local $| = 1;

my $pop = Net::POP3->new('pop.mail.server');

print "Logging in....";
if ($pop->login('username','password')) {
 print "logged in successfully\n";
 my $msgs = $pop->list;
 my @keys = keys(%$msgs);
 my $msgr = $pop->get($keys[1]); #Selects a more or less random email for testing
 my $msg = join("",@$msgr);

 my $parsed = Email::MIME->new($msg);
 foreach my $key (keys %$parsed) {print $key.":".$parsed{$key}."\n";}
}
```

Output:

```
Logging in....logged in successfully
body:
mycrlf:
body_raw:
parts:
ct:
header:
```

Comment: Have you printed `$msg`, to see if that contains what looks like an e-mail message with headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  This will immediately point out an error:

`Global symbol "%parsed" requires explicit package name at p line 21.`

Line 21 should be:

```
foreach my $key (keys %$parsed) {print $key.":".$parsed->{$key}."\n";}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be `$parsed->{ $key }` in your print statement